# How many hidden layers a CNN has?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, layer, conv-neural-network

I use a CNN for a classification problem. The code for the architecture of the model is below:

```
model.add(Conv1D(256, 5,padding='same',
                 input_shape=(40,1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 5,padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(8)))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 5,padding='same',))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 5,padding='same',))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(8))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
opt = keras.optimizers.rmsprop(lr=0.00001, decay=1e-6)
```

How many hidden layers this model has? Also which one is the output and the input layer?

Comment: I believe that every .add function is considered an input layer, except for the last one (activation). However, this question doesn't necessarily belong to stack overflow. Please consider this link here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/keras/keras_layers.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the input layer is the first layer(the one where the input_shape is specified) . Each time you use model.add a new layer is created. You can use model.summary() to print out your model layer structure as shown below.

```
Model: "sequential_8"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_20 (Conv1D)           (None, 40, 256)           1536      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_23 (Activation)   (None, 40, 256)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_21 (Conv1D)           (None, 40, 128)           163968    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_24 (Activation)   (None, 40, 128)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_6 (Dropout)          (None, 40, 128)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_4 (MaxPooling1 (None, 5, 128)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_22 (Conv1D)           (None, 5, 128)            82048     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_25 (Activation)   (None, 5, 128)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_23 (Conv1D)           (None, 5, 128)            82048     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_26 (Activation)   (None, 5, 128)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_3 (Flatten)          (None, 640)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 8)                 5128      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_27 (Activation)   (None, 8)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 334,728
Trainable params: 334,728
Non-trainable params: 0
```

This can be a bit confusing in the sense that your actual output layer is the layer with 8 nodes and the softmax activation function. I prefer to create models as follows

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(40,1))
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(256, 5,padding='same', activation='relu')(inputs)
x=Dropout(.1)(x)
x=MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(8))(x)
x=Conv1D(128, 5,padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
x=Conv1D(128, 5,padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
x=Conv1D(128, 5,padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
x=Flatten()(x)
outputs=Dense(8, activation='softmax')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

It is the exact same model but I think it is clearer as to what layer is the actual output
See result below for model.summary()

> Blockquote
Model: "model_6"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_9 (InputLayer)         [(None, 40, 1)]           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_44 (Conv1D)           (None, 40, 256)           1536      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_15 (Dropout)         (None, 40, 256)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_12 (MaxPooling (None, 5, 256)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_45 (Conv1D)           (None, 5, 128)            163968    
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_46 (Conv1D)           (None, 5, 128)            82048     
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_47 (Conv1D)           (None, 5, 128)            82048     
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_11 (Flatten)         (None, 640)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_12 (Dense)             (None, 8)                 5128      
=================================================================
Total params: 334,728
Trainable params: 334,728
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: Thank you! So how many hidden layers this model has?

Comment: Also the input layer is the first convolution layer? Or they are different layers?

Comment: the input layer is a separate layer and not a convolutional layer

Answer (score 2):

The first layer is the input layer and the last one is the output layer. Whatever comes in between these two are the hidden layers.

```
model.add(Conv1D(256, 5,padding='same', input_shape=(40,1))) # input layer
model.add(Activation('relu')) # hidden layer
model.add(Conv1D(128, 5,padding='same')) # hidden layer
model.add(Activation('relu')) # hidden layer
model.add(Dropout(0.1)) # hidden layer
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(8))) # hidden layer
model.add(Conv1D(128, 5,padding='same',)) # hidden layer 
model.add(Activation('relu')) # hidden layer
model.add(Conv1D(128, 5,padding='same',)) #hidden layer
model.add(Activation('relu')) # hidden layer
model.add(Flatten()) # hidden layer
model.add(Dense(8)) # hidden layer
model.add(Activation('softmax')) # output layer
opt = keras.optimizers.rmsprop(lr=0.00001, decay=1e-6)
```